# Sum of four numbers less than a particular value

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have four positive numbers $a_1,\dots,a_4$, each less than $45$. How many different ways are there for $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4<90$? I require different permutations i.e $a_1a_2a_3a_4$ is different from  $a_2a_1a_4a_3$

Comment: Any numbers? Perhaps you mean integers, or positive integers? Your question is ambiguous. If any numbers are allowed, there are infinitely many combinations.

Comment: Also, would you consider $a_1=21$, $a_2=a_3=a_4=20$ to be a different answer than $a_2=21,$ $a_1=a_3=a_4=20$, or the same thing? That makes a **crucial** difference. It looks like you probably interpret them to be different, given the `permutations` tag. Is this correct?

Comment: it should be positive integers

Comment: Rolled back: The previous edit introduced 3 changes: each a_i should be *positive*, each a_i is *less than* 45, the sum of the a_i's should be *less than* 90.

Comment: Related: [Four positive numbers less than 10 must add up to 12](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372624/probability-of-random-integers-digits-summing-to-12).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution by generating functions:
Let $F(x)=(x+x^2+\cdots+x^{44})^4(x+x^2+\cdots)$. I claim that we seek the coefficient of $x^{90}$. Indeed, the statement is equivalent to $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+c=90$, for some positive $a_1,\cdots a_4,c$ with $a_1,\cdots a_4<45$. The coefficients of $(x+x^2+\cdots+x^{44})^4$ represent the number of ways to choose $1\le a_1,\cdots a_4\le 44$ such that they add to a certain exponent. The $(x+x^2+\cdots)$ term does the same thing, but there is no upper bound.

Now, we rearrange and obtain
$$
F(x)=\frac{x^5(1-x^{44})^4}{(1-x)^5}=\frac{x^{181}-4 x^{136}+6 x^{93}-4 x^{49}+x^5}{(1-x)^5}
$$
It is well known that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)^m}$ is $\binom{m+k-1}{k}$ (this can be easily proven by induction by using $\frac{1}{(1-x)}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$). Then the number that we seek is
$$
-4\binom{45}{41}+\binom{89}{85}=1845646
$$
Which was confirmed with Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ the same as $(a_1,a_2,a_4,a_3) \ \ldots$ then according to python the answer is $90316$. 
If $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ and $(a_1,a_2,a_4,a_3)$ are considered different $\ldots$ then the answer is $1898622$.

Comment: I do not require direct answer. I want to solve it by permuatation and combinations

Answer (score 0):

OP wanted a permutation and combination solution, and the two posted solutions don't tally, so here is a [Stars and Bars Th.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach.

Here we necessarily need a *positive* slack variable *s* to convert this inequality, which is of the $<$ type, into an equality, and so we need to solve
$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+s = 90$ over the positive integers, and by Th. $1$ of stars and bars, along with inclusion-exclusion (actually, just exclusion, as luckily only one variable can violate the upper bound), we get
$$Answer\; = \binom{89}{4} - 4\binom{45}{4}= 1845646$$

Comment: For $a_i<45$ the value $1845646$ is correct. The value $1898622$ is obtained for $a_i\le45$.

Comment: GF counts sums totaling $90$

Comment: But it is taking *c* (the slack variable) to be necessarily $\ge1$

Comment: $\sum a_i<90\implies c>0$

Comment: Yea, I didn't think of that, am amending, thanks.