# Probability of random integer's digits summing to 12

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

What is the probability that a random integer between 1 and 9999 will have digits that sum to 12?

As a user suggested, I could make a spreadsheet and count them, but is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: For a range like this, why not make a spreadsheet and count them?

Comment: Your question is phrased as a stand-alone problem, without any further information or context. This does not match our quality standards, and hence is likely to attract downvotes, or be closed. It is impossible for us to assess your issues with the problem, and the level of answer appropriate for you. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) is a guide to asking a good question. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. This helps attract more appropriate answers and will likely remove down- and close votes.

Comment: I vote against closing this question.

Comment: also depends on the distribution

Comment: I also vote against closing this question.

Comment: This question has produced many surprisingly interesting answers ... and is obviously of interest to a large number of people. Many have expressed their desire to see it remain open by voting above. Notwithstanding same, 5 users .. namely TheChaz2.0, Lord_Farin, rschweib, DavidGiraudo and Landscape have voted to close it. I believe this reflects poor judgement on their part. I suspect this matter should appropriately be referred to a meta thread for discussion. @MJD /// would you like to open a thread there?

Comment: I do not want to open a meta thread.  You are welcome to do so if you like.

Comment: @TheChaz I am *very* disappointed to see valid questions like this being closed for strange reasons, e.g. "too localized". Ditto for analogous recent votes.

Comment: I agree that this is a reasonably interesting question and would also like to block a future close vote. (Certainly it's more interesting than the median question.)

Comment: @MathGems: there is no option to "close for the reasons that The Chaz 2.0 mentions in [his meta answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9195/7850)", so I just pick one. Everyone is free to vote: up, down, close, open. And nobody has to agree with me. I don't mind being in the minority in this case. It's open and receiving answers. win-win

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 There appears to have been a spike of rash closure decisions recently (perhaps sparked by meta threads). I hope that those involved will exercise more careful judgment in the future. If taken to extremes such voting could have very harmful effects. In particular, it might alienate the teachers who could best answer *your* questions. Is that what you desire?

Answer (score 32):

The problem does not require a spreadsheet.  It does not even require paper.

The question is to count the number of integer tuples $\langle a,b,c,d\rangle$ with $a+b+c+d=12$ and $0\le a,b,c,d < 10$. We could enumerate this  by choosing $a$ and then counting the tuples $\langle b,c,d\rangle$ with $b+c+d = 12-a$, and recursing, but an easier method is available.

First, note that if we drop the $a,b,c,d < 10$ restriction, the problem is easy.  By the [stars and bars method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), there are $\binom{15}{12} = 455$ tuples that sum to 12.

From these 455 we need to eliminate the ones that contain $10, 11,$ or $12$.
Let $t_i$ be the number of tuples where  $a =i$ for $i\in\{10,11,12\}$.  Clearly, $t_{12} = 1$: the only tuple is $\langle 12, 0,0,0\rangle$.  For $a=11$ we need $b+c+d=1$, so exactly one of $b,c,d$ is 1 and the other two are 0, and thus $t_{11} = 3$.

For $a=10$ there are two possibilities.  Either $\{b,c,d\} = \{2,0,0\}$ or $\{b,c,d\} = \{1,1,0\}$.  In either case there are 3 tuples, so $t_{10} = 6$.

Since at most one of $a,b,c,d$ is greater than 9, the total number of tuples that contain 10, 11, or 12 is $4(t_{10}+t_{11}+t_{12}) = 40$.

Thus the total number of tuples of just 0 through 9, and the answer to the question, is 455 - 40 = 415; the probability is $\frac{415}{9999}$.

Comment: Note that with the range starting at 1, leading zeros are explicitly OK.  This makes it easier.

Comment: There are several features of this problem that make it easier than it seems at first: leading zeroes are acceptable, so $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are symmetric. The required sum is close to 9, so only a few integer tuples need to be subtracted, and no inclusion-exclusion argument is needed.  Recognizing such features when they appear can be an important aspect of solving this type of problem.

Comment: Does not even require paper?? :) Neither did mine

Comment: The problem does not require an integer either. What is the probability that randomly chosen combination of four numbers in the range 0 to 9 adds up to to twelve.

Comment: @Kaz Probability is 0, because if you permit $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4$, even restricting the possible range to between 0 and 9, $a+b+c+d=12$ is still a three-dimentional figure.  That's like asking what the probability that a random point in a plane happens to lie on a given line, or the probability that a randomly chosen number just happens to be _exactly the same_ as a given number.  Without restricting the digits to integers, the problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 16):

Use generating functions.  The generating function for a single digit is:

$$1 + x + \cdots + x^9 = \frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}.$$

The generating function for the sum of four digits is the fourth power:

$$\frac{(1-x^{10})^4}{(1-x)^4} = (1-x^{10})^4 (1-x)^{-4}.$$

To solve the problem, find the coefficient of $x^{12}$.

$$(1-x^{10})^4 = 1 -4 x^{10} + 6 x^{20} - \cdots$$

So, we only need the coefficients of $x^2$ and $x^{12}$ in $(1-x)^{-4}$ using the generalized binomial theorem. These are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ and $\binom{15}{12} = 455$. The coefficient of $x^{12}$ is therefore

$$ -4\cdot10 + 1\cdot455 = 415.$$

So the answer is $\frac{415}{9999}$.

Comment: where do 5,2,15 and 12 come from in ncr(5, 2) and ncr(15, 12)?

Comment: @michaelsnowden The coefficient of $x^2$ in $(1 - x)^{-4}$ is $(-1)^2\binom{-4}{2} = \binom{4 + 2 - 1}{2}$, because of the binomial theorem which says that the coefficient of $z^n$ in $(1+z)^n$ is $\binom{n}{r}$, and the fact that $\binom{-n}{r} = (-1)^r\binom{n + r - 1}{r}$. Similarly, the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(1-x)^{-4}$ is $(-1)^{12}\binom{-4}{12} = \binom{4 + 12 - 1}{12}$.

Comment: In general, if we're looking for $k$ random digits summing to $n$, by this answer we're looking for the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-x^{10})^k (1-x)^{-k}$. This is going to be $$\sum_{10r+s=n} (-1)^{r+s} \binom{k}{r} \binom{-k}{s} = \sum_{10r+s=n} (-1)^{r} \binom{k}{r} \binom{k+s-1}{s}$$ if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 10):

With Mathematica code (FROM 1 TO 9999):

```
Count[Map[Total, IntegerDigits[Range[9999]]], 12]
```

> 415

So: 415/9999

Comment: As an alternative approach: `Probability[x == 12, 
 x \[Distributed] Total[IntegerDigits[Range[9999]], {2}]]` directly yields `415/9999`.

Comment: Wow, "FrankenLisp".

Answer (score 5):

Just so [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) doesn't get left out.  Here's a GAP version to obtain the count:

```
Number([1..9999],n->Sum(ListOfDigits(n))=12);
```

which returns `415`.  So, the probability is $415/9999$.

Comment: Go GAP! Good to see it's still around and alive.

Answer (score 4):

With PARI/GP code

> `Q(n)=if(n<10,n,n%10 + Q(n\10))`
>
> `sum(i=1,9999,Q(i)==12)/9999`

I obtain
$$\frac{415}{9999}.$$