# How can I find the sum of the digits of a positive integer in GAP?

Tags: math-software, computer-algebra-systems, gap

(I eventually found the answer to this question after writing it.  But just in case anyone finds this useful, or has an alternative or better answer, I'll ask and answer my own question.)

After seeing slick Mathematica code for the question [Probability of random integer's digits summing to 12](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372624/139), I found myself stumped as to how to sum the digits of a positive integer in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/).

> **Question**: How can I find the sum of the digits of a positive integer in GAP?

Thus far, I've used my own code when required:

```
DecimalDigits:=function(n)
  if(n=0) then
    return [];
  else
    return Concatenation(DecimalDigits(Int(n/10)),[n mod 10]);
  fi;
end;;
```

In this format, e.g. `DecimalDigits(1234)` returns the array `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` which can be summed by `Sum(DecimalDigits(1234))`.  But, I'm hoping there is a better way to do this (particularly in the newer versions of GAP).

The `DigitsNumber` function returns a string, on which `Sum` doesn't work.

Comment: +1 nice question. I am your supporter to spread using GAP here :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: BTW, have you seen http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50072/mathematics-software-other-than-mathematica ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you, Douglas. I would like to add some remarks, but it seems like I can't include GAP code conveniently in comments, and can't fit them in the length limit. Thus, let me post them as an answer :)

1) I think that `ListOfDigits` is meant to be a utility function for small inputs. If one really wants to compute sums of digits more efficiently, one could start with looking what `ListOfDigits` is doing and then write an own `SumOfDigits` function.

In the following GAP session we compare the performance of `SumOfDigits` vs.`Sum(ListOfDigits(...))` approach:

```
gap> SumOfDigits:=function(a)
> local s, b;
> if not a in NonnegativeIntegers then 
>   Error("a must be a non-negative integer");
> fi;
> s:=0;
> while a<>0 do
>   b:=a mod 10;
>   s:=s+b;
>   a:=(a-b)/10;
> od;
> return s;
> end;
function( a ) ... end
gap> ForAll([1..10000],i->SumOfDigits(i)=Sum(ListOfDigits(i)));
true
gap> for i in [1..1000000] do x:=SumOfDigits(i); od; time;
1426
gap> for i in [1..1000000] do x:=Sum(ListOfDigits(i)); od; time;
3560
gap> for i in [1..10000000] do x:=SumOfDigits(i); od; time;
16364
gap> for i in [1..10000000] do x:=Sum(ListOfDigits(i)); od; time;
38255
```

Clearly, `SumOfDigits` doesn't have to store an intermediate list of digits, handling which becomes more and more expensive with larger inputs.

2) The new version of GAP indeed may show better performance in this example if compared with GAP 4.4.12, since starting from GAP 4.5 by default the GAP kernel uses the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/) for faster integer arithmetic.

3) I haven't compared the performance of the `DecimalDigits` function given above, but I have observed that it will not work for large inputs:

```
gap> Length(DecimalDigits(10^4997));
4998
gap> DecimalDigits(10^4998);;
Error, recursion depth trap (5000)
 in
  return Concatenation( DecimalDigits( Int( n / 10 ) ), [ n mod 10 ] ); called from 
DecimalDigits( Int( n / 10 ) ) called from
DecimalDigits( Int( n / 10 ) ) called from
DecimalDigits( Int( n / 10 ) ) called from
DecimalDigits( Int( n / 10 ) ) called from
DecimalDigits( Int( n / 10 ) ) called from
...  at line 57 of *stdin*
you may 'return;'
brk>
```

where `SumOfDigits` will work. (The `recursion depth trap` error is a special error in GAP preventing it from running into an infinite recursion). Also please note that the GAP Tutorial chapter on Functions says: "Regardless of the recursive structure of an algorithm it is often cheaper (in terms of computing time) to avoid a recursive implementation if possible (and it is possible in this case), because a function call is not very cheap."

4) Of course, in the last example with 10^n one does not need to ask any system what the sum of digits is :)

Comment: OMG!. I am surrounded by these beautiful great well defined approach.

Comment: Great!  That's even better.  It seems there's no in-built SumOfDigits(...) function, though.

Comment: *Note*: the `<pre>` environment is incompatible with GAP's `<>` (which I think is interpreted as HTML code).  Consequently, in the previous version `a<>0` appears as `a0`.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I've discovered that GAP's `<>` disappeared in my first submission and then replaced "less than" by HTML entity to fix this. I've seen your edit - is there any other alternative to publish code except indenting it with four spaces?

Comment: Surely there is no `SumOfDigits` in GAP, it was written especially for this answer. The reader interested in using it should copy the code from above and paste it into his/her GAP session or a file to be read in GAP.

Comment: Yes `<pre><code>a<>b</code></pre>` also works.

Comment: SumOfDigits(-1) fails. :-)  Maybe "if not a in NonnegativeIntegers then return fail; fi;" at the top.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: indeed, thanks! Well, the title of the question says that _a_ is positive. For negative _a_, perhaps returning the sum of digits of _-a_ is another option. Finally, this may be turned into an operation declared for `IsInt`.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: just to note that I've edited my reply and added an error when _a_ is not a non-negative integer.

Comment: Looks good. infinite loops are surprising to new users. :-) One thing I like about GAP versus Pari is its argument checking.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones: thanks for your hint, but `<pre><code>a<>b</code></pre>` works in a comment, but not in an answer :-(

Answer (score 2):

The `ListOfDigits` function in GAP converts a positive integer into the corresponding list of decimal digits.

For example  `ListOfDigits(1234);` returns `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`.  After which the sum of the digits can be found as usual: `Sum(ListOfDigits(1234));`.

Here's the result of `?ListOfDigits` ([ref.](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap14.html); 14.2-11):

```
  14.2-11 ListOfDigits

  ‣ ListOfDigits( n ) ────────────────────────────── function

  For  a  positive  integer n this function returns a list l,
  consisting of the digits of n in decimal representation.

  ────────────────────────  Example  ────────────────────────
    gap> ListOfDigits(3142);   
    [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ]
  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```